# uploaded my angular app, nothing but blank page showing

Tags: angular

just finished my angular app.

`ng serve -o` works perfectly. `ng build -- prod` works.

but getting a blank page after uploading to the server, no errors on console.

after uploading the app to my server, the index.html page shows in the browser, with title in the browser tab, background-color correct, even favicon shows up, but other than that the page is blank. It's like angular is not running.

page here:

http://www.appdigity.com/ptp/

any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I would try to verify that everything is uploaded properly. If your hosting company has a file explorer I would check there first.

From what I am seeing in the console when I go to the site, there's a lot of 404's.
[image]

Comment: interesting... for some reason, none of those are showing up in my console.

Comment: Odd..... after a few page refreshes I am now seeing your favicon and what not. I'm not seeing those 404s any longer.. 

Are you using angular CLI?

Comment: it seems to be loading my index page fine, but not routing properly. :(

Answer (score 2):

If still your app is not working then try to add this in your `index.html` file.

There will be this line `<base href="/">`, just put dot before `/` like this `<base href="./">`.. and then try again.

Comment: hmm, tried all of these. still not working. index page loads, but it is not routing to my main page.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this just happened to me and may help someone else:

installed @nestjs/ng-universal $ ng add @nestjs/ng-universal
the angular project I´m working on already had @nguniversal installed, I´ve uninstalled manually all I´ve found related to it.
so when I´ve installed this new package, it modified the again /src/main.ts, wrapping twice the boostrap.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
        platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
    });
});
```

This give me a blank page running $ ng serve with no error, no message, no nothing, just a white and nasty page.
After deleting one of the document.addEventListener( ... wrappers, it worked!